# How to use variables Inside create view inside Procedure?

Tags: postgresql

I have a case where i want to create a view inside a procedure.

Works fine (Usage of variables)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE createViewForAnalysis(analysis INT)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    Perform
        code,
        isReport,
        description,
        SUM(dialoge) as dialoge,
        SUM(response_time) as response_time,
            SUM(response_time)/NULLIF(SUM(dialoge),0) as avg_response_time
    FROM codes_joined WHERE analyse_id=analysis
    GROUP BY code, isReport ,description;

END;
$$;
```

Also works fine (create view with fixed value in where)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE createViewForAnalysis(analysis INT)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tcodes_aggregated AS
    SELECT
        code,
        isReport,
        description,
        SUM(dialoge) as dialoge,
        SUM(response_time) as response_time,
        SUM(response_time)/NULLIF(SUM(dialoge),0) as avg_response_time
    FROM codes_joined AS pg WHERE analyse_id=1
    GROUP BY code, isReport ,description;

END;
$$;
```

When I want to use a variable inside a create view it doesn't take the value inside analysis. It throws 
"[42703] ERROR: column "analysis" does not exist"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE createViewForAnalysis(analysis INT)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tcodes_aggregated AS
    SELECT
        code,
        isReport,
        beschreibung,
        SUM(dialoge) as dialoge,
        SUM(response_time) as response_time,
        SUM(response_time)/NULLIF(SUM(dialoge),0) as avg_response_time
    FROM codes_joined AS pg WHERE analyse_id=analysis
    GROUP BY code, isReport ,description;

END;
$$;
```

Any hints?

Comment: I find this interesting.  As I understand, the crux is, how to pass the variable into the create view statement with "WHERE analyse_id=1".  Answers provide different approach to get similar results - but why can't the parameter be used as in "insert into table values (analysis)" for example?

Answer (score 1):

Views can't have parameters or variables. I think what you want is a SQL function that returns the result of the query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function view_for_analysis(analysis INT)
  returns table (code integer, isreport boolean, beschreibung text, dialoge bigint, response_time bigint, avg_response_time numeric)
AS
$$
SELECT
    code,
    isReport,
    beschreibung,
    SUM(dialoge) as dialoge,
    SUM(response_time) as response_time,
    SUM(response_time)/NULLIF(SUM(dialoge),0) as avg_response_time
FROM codes_joined AS pg 
WHERE analyse_id = analysis
GROUP BY code, isReport ,description;
$$;
language SQL;
```

Note that I guessed the data types of the columns. You will have to adjust the `returns table()` part to the actual data types of your table.

Then you use it like this:

```
select *
from view_for_analysis(42);
```

Answer (score 1):

Views can't have parameters, but you can create views dynamically using [dynamic commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE createViewForAnalysis(analysis INT)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tcodes_aggregated AS
        SELECT
            code,
            isReport,
            beschreibung,
            SUM(dialoge) as dialoge,
            SUM(response_time) as response_time,
            SUM(response_time)/NULLIF(SUM(dialoge),0) as avg_response_time
        FROM codes_joined AS pg WHERE analyse_id=' || analysis ||
        'GROUP BY code, isReport, description;';

END;
$$;
```